# Forgot to export revolution slider

Tags: slider

Actually i was migrating my wordpress website with 5 sliders from one aws account to another by using all in one migration plugin. But i forgot to export all the sliders from dashboard and i exported the file. And cleaned the old account's wordpress dashboard. Now after importing this migration file in new aws account's wordpress , everything is same but my sliders are not showing and in youtube people are importing their slider that they exported earlier from revolution slider. Now i am unable to find them they took me 1 whole week to make them. Please anyone help

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to contact your hosting provider and restore your old Website. There is no way to recover your sliders once it's removed.